# Dataframe from JSON formatted as text?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

Is it possible to create a dataframe from JSON formatted as text, not as Python object?

With Python object, I could for example do:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import requests

response = requests.get(url, params).json()
df = json_normalize(response)
```

but I want to achieve the same with `response = requests.get(url,params).text` (flattening is not required though).

Comment: Can you put  few lines of the data?

Comment: @pygo why the list comprehension?

Comment: @pygo I won't be reading JSON from file, I want to put `requests.get(url,params).text` response into a dataframe.

Comment: @barciewicz, yes got it thats y i said i misread tehe question sorry :-)

Comment: Is the `.text` guaranteed to be valid JSON string?

Answer (score 1):

If your `response = requests.get(url,params).text` is guaranteed to give you a valid JSON string, then all you need to do is as follows:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize, loads
import requests

response = requests.get(url, params).text
df = json_normalize(loads(response))
```

Here we make use of `json`'s `loads` to convert the JSON string to a Python object before passing back to `json_normalize`.

Answer (score 0):

I usually create dataframe from json using "read_json"

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

data = requests.get(url, params).content
df = pd.read_json(data)
df.head()
```

Comment: Thanks, sadly  this gives me `ValueError: arrays must all be same length` at `read_json` line, I guess because my JSON is nested. Do you know how to work around it?

Comment: replace read_json line by:

    from pandas.io.json import json_normalize, loads
    df = json_normalize(loads(data))